# How to share validation rules of several models and a large ajax form that holds them

Tags: ajax, forms, validation, octobercms

I have a large ajax managed form with several steps. Obviously, I need to validate data after each submit step. The final validation results in the creation of several business objects.

Some business objects will receive all of their fields, others will not. For example, the customer who will not receive the billing address (it will be requested at the time the billing takes place). Indeed, the form being very long, I do not want to overload it by adding elements not immediately useful.

Some form partial concern only few informations 
hold by my model so i can't instanciate model just for validation of little % of his attributes.

In principe, with October, the validation is done at the level of the models by adding the trait validator which will make it possible to use the generic Laravel validation functionalities (perhaps i'm wrong here)
But I'm not sure I can use on the models validation because some will be incomplete at the end of the form filling.

It is necessary to mutualize the validation of all these data without making a gas factory with duplicate validation code but how, where?
For the moment I am on the idea of ​​making a trait added to my object component which handles all my ajax handlers but I am not excited because it does not correspond to my idea to mutualize the validation

Perhaps using behavior instead of traits are better

https://octobercms.com/docs/services/behaviors

to be continued ...

Answer (score 0):

If I had to do it, I'll use the Validation service after each submit step.
https://octobercms.com/docs/services/validation

You can store the info in a session and use them at the final stage.

```
$myinput = post('myinput');
$validator = Validator::make(
    [
        'myinput' => $myinput
    ],
    [
        'myinput' => 'required|min:8'
    ]
);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    // The given data did not pass validation
}

// store in session
Session::push('myform.myinput', $myinput);
Session::push('myform.step', 2);
```

PS: on est deux francophones qui se causent en anglais :)

Comment: merci Pierre-André :-) yes that a good way to do but i to have to put some validation rules at the form level and these same rules at the model, so i'm thinkink about an architecture to mutualize at the same place, not simple

Comment: Have you an idea of good practice for mutualize validation rules among form and models (without instanciate model obviously) ?

Comment: maybe a start of solution here : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/reuse-validation-rules-in-form-request-in-another-form-request